# How to make a Custom Dialog stay on top of its parent without being on top of other applications

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am sorry if this question lacks detail.  I'm not sure what detail to give that wouldn't be irrelevant to the overall essence of the question, which is..

How do I cause one form to always be on top of another, without causing it to be on top of everything (as is the case when I set the 'TopMost' property to true)

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and this is a WinForms (Windows Forms) application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in an "owner" to Show() like this:

```
MyCustomDialog.Show(this);
```

*Assuming that code was being executed by the "parent" form.

Comment: My original code was already doing that.   I may not have had the calling form set as the parent.  I did try MyCustomDialog.Parent = this; after creation but I got a compile error.

Anyway, the ShowDialog(); does exactly what I need :)

Comment: Correction: I think my code was passing the calling form (this) in the constructor,  not the show.  My mistake.  With this in mind I'll see if your solution also works when I get home.

Comment: I've had a chance to test, and this does keep the form on top while allowing me to interact with the parent form.  I prefer this to what I found so I have changed my code to use this method.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer...

```
MyCustomDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Instead of...

```
MyCustomDialog.Show();
```

Will achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This kind of showing the child dialog is called Modal dialog. In this case you can not interact with the parent dialog while the child is being displayed.

Comment: I am ok with that in this case.    When I can I will see what Idle_Mind's solution does and see if it is preferable.